# How to write '&' character to xml using Transformer Factory in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to re write special characters in xml as

```
< as & lt;
  > as &gt;
  & as &amp;
  ' as &apos;
  " as &quot;
```

I m using escapeXml() of StringEscapeUtils class and transformer factory to       write the xml.
but what it does is it is rewriting

```
> as &gt;
```

and again `&` as `&amp;` and appending it to `gt;` and writing as `&amp;gt;`
how do i write `>` as `&gt;` alone.
Please help me as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry for the improper format, it is writing > as &amp;gt;. how do i write as > as &gt;

Comment: If you escape the string once, it shouldn't be a problem, but it seems you escape the string twice now. If you made an escape function yourself, make sure to replace `&` with `&amp;` as the first step, otherwise that step will also escape as the `&` of other entities as you have noticed. If you still can't solve it, please post your code.

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE.

Comment: StringEscapeUtils is not a JDK class, is it?

Comment: Are you using Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils? It will replace < with &lt; and so on..

Comment: thanks Syam. I m escaping only once. but it is rewriting as such. indirectly it is escaping twice. ya i use StringEscapeUtils from Apache Commons. I also tried creating my own function, using String.replace. In that case also it is writing twice.

Comment: input=prop.getAttribute("VALUE");

Comment: if(input.contains("<")||input.contains(">")|| input.contains("'")||input.contains("\"")||input.contains("<>")){

Comment: input=StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(input);

Comment: This is my code. here immediately if i check after the above line, it returns > as &gt; only

Comment: but while writing it is escaping again and printing as &amp;gt;